# Enter Admin password when prompted by RunAs cmd

Tags: command-line, installation, batch, passwords

I'm installing a remote control application on about 100+ machines
The current logged in users can not "Run As Administrator"
I'm using the runas command to run as the local admin but it prompts for the password still.
Here is my batch command.

```
@Echo Off

runas /user:localadmin "c:\users\localuser\desktop\control.exe"

Timeout /t 10 >nul

Del "c:\users\localuser\desktop\Install.bat","c:\users\localuser\desktop\control.exe"

Exit
```

What I get when I run this is "Enter the password for localadmin:"

I always have to enter the password.
Then it continues correctly.

**How can I automate the input?**

Comment: If a non-admin user could run a command as admin, what would be the point?

Comment: It's strictly for automation. I need the users to run the batch file and I don't want to have to ask them to enter the password. It's not a huge secret, its just cumbersome.

Comment: If the computers are in a domain and you have the ability to reach them over the network, consider starting a powershell session as admin on your computer, then use enter-pssession computername to connect to another computer and you should be able to run your script elevated, or at least enter the password yourself. There are also methods to run a script remotely entirely using powershell.

Comment: These machines are not in a domain, they are POS computers at 75+ locations with no interconnectivity between each other. They are all logged into a limited user account that can't even right click.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible to automate the password entering?

Yes, but every method you want to use will somehow store the password, such that a clever user may be able to retrieve it.

One way to do it, is by storing the password in a textfile along with an enter (new line) and then use the command as follows:

```
runas /user:localadmin "c:\users\localuser\desktop\control.exe" < password.txt
```

What this does is use password.txt as input as if these are entered in console by a user. Every keypress you make that produces a character will be transmitted to your command.

The downside is that you store the password in a textfile that can be opened. You could generate the password.txt (or whatever you name the file) in your script, but then your script has the password in plain text stored which is not ideal either.

If your computers are domain joined, it would be far more interesting to distribute the installer through group policy. This makes it so you only have to make the computer reboot to get the software installed.

Comment: i used my script to create the txt file and used the syntax like you suggested, but i think that there is a space or return that being picked up when calling it. any way around that?

Comment: Without seeing your code, its impossible for me to assertain why things aren't working correctly.

Comment: @Echo Off

Echo [password]> "c:\users\user1\desktop\install.txt"
runas /user:localadmin "c:\users\user1\desktop\control.exe" < "c:\users\user1\desktop\install.txt"

Timeout /t 10 >nul

Del "c:\users\user1\desktop\Install.bat","c:\users\user1\desktop\control.exe","c:\users\user1\desktop\install.txt"

Exit

Comment: Try adding `echo. >> "C:\users\user1\desktop\install.txt"` to ensure there is a newline.

Comment: @LPChip: In what Windows are you? I'm on Windows 10 and this doesn't work for me eighter. Error code 1325 wrong username or password but I'm sure the password is right it works if you manually type in the password without using the text file

Comment: @RicardoBohner I'm on Windows10 myself. Make sure that the password.txt file exists in that path, or otherwise provide a path.

Comment: Yes the password.txt is in the same path where I'm running the command. Have you tested this yourself cause I always heard that you can't pipe to runas command for security reasons?

Comment: @LPChip tested on Windows 7 also without succsess